# Create sitemap from routes.ini?

Tags: zend-framework, navigation, routes, sitemap

Is it possible to automatically generate a sitemap in xml from routes set up in routes.ini in ZF1?

My routes are set up like this in routes.ini

```
resources.router.routes.homepage.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route"
resources.router.routes.homepage.route = "/@lang/@home"
resources.router.routes.homepage.defaults.lang = "en"
resources.router.routes.homepage.defaults.module = "default"
resources.router.routes.homepage.defaults.controller = "index"
resources.router.routes.homepage.defaults.action = "index"
resources.router.routes.homepage.reqs.lang = "[a-z]{2}"
```

indicating the routes are translated which will be extra complicating, but even automatically creating a sitemap non translated would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think so. The `routes.ini` defines abstract routes... For example if you have a slug in a route (or a category) that will change on different pages with almost the same route:

```
/home/default/view/page_name1
/home/default/view/page_name2
```

are two different entities in the `sitemap.xml` and at the same time `routes.ini` does not make a distinction between to two.

So it really depends on your site structure & functionaloty.

I don't think that there is such a tool that will do this automatically for you.